# WordPress URL Rewrite unable to get second matches

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

My URL is `http://example.com/locate/ny/2`

in functions, I use below code

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('locate/([^/]+)','index.php?page_id=294&cs=$matches[1]','top');
```

I got URL like this `http://example.com/locate/ny` I got this working, but i want to add a pagination after ny  like  `ny?cpaged=3` and rewrite to `ny/3`

but what is the regexp for `index.php?page_id=294&cs=$matches[1]&cpaged=$matches[2]` from url `http://example.com/locate/ny/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another capturing group within the regex that just picks out the digits from the url. Assuming your url structure isn't going to change this regex should work.

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('locate\/([^\/]+)\/(\d*)','index.php?page_id=294&cs=$matches[1]&cpaged=$matches[2]','top');
```

See here for a demo and to play around with it further: https://regex101.com/r/BNkZBo/1/